# R list.files ignore system files

Tags: regex, r, file

I am using a command like below to get list of files in a folder.

My pattern argument is not working correctly. I want to pull a list of only jpg or csv files. How should i set my pattern argument?

Moreover, that folder contains .RData and .Rhistory files that are created by the system. I didnt put them. In such case is there an easier way to ignore system files when i compile a list of files in a folder?

```
filenames=list.files(path = "//c:/ch7data", pattern = "*.jpg|*.csv")
```

-------------------------update1

as per suggestions provided in one of the answers I used below code, but it didnt seem to work :(.

I got .Rdata and .rhistory and also . and .. I dont want these files/values.

I want only jpg and csv and xlsx files in the variable filenames

```
filenames=list.files(path = "//C:/ch7data", all.files = TRUE)
> filenames
 [1] "."                           ".."                          ".RData"                      ".Rhistory"                  
 [5] "CH7Data_20130401T130110.csv" "CH7Data_20130401T130110.jpg" "CH7Data_20130401T130610.csv" "CH7Data_20130401T130610.jpg"
 [9] "CH7Data_20130401T131610.csv" "CH7Data_20130401T131610.jpg" "CH7Data_20130401T135010.csv" "CH7Data_20130401T135010.jpg"
[13] "ffa.xlsx"                    "Thumbs.db"
```

-----------------------update2

I used a command as below and it avoided . , .. , .Rdata and .rhistory :)
any way to avoid thumbs.db ?

```
> filenames=list.files(path = "//C:/ch7data", all.files = FALSE, no..=TRUE)

> filenames
 [1] "CH7Data_20130401T130110.csv" "CH7Data_20130401T130110.jpg" "CH7Data_20130401T130610.csv" "CH7Data_20130401T130610.jpg"
 [5] "CH7Data_20130401T131610.csv" "CH7Data_20130401T131610.jpg" "CH7Data_20130401T135010.csv" "CH7Data_20130401T135010.jpg"
 [9] "ffa.xlsx"                    "Thumbs.db"
```

Answer (score 2):

To get only files that ends with **.jpg** or **.csv**, you can use the following pattern:

```
list.files(path = "//c:/ch7data", pattern = "^(.*)+(\\.jpg|\\.csv)$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
 Sys.glob(file.path("c:","ch7data",c("*.jpg","*.csv")))
```

1. Better to use globs rather than regular expressions
2. Use `file.path` to create path in OS independent manner.